# Can BigQuery views be listed as entities under BQ Dataset assets in GCP Dataplex?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-dataplex

In the current usecase, I am using authorized views to handle row level security in the BigQuery dataset and Dataplex to handle the governance and permissions.

When a BQ Dataset is added as an asset, only the tables under it are getting listed as entities and the views are not listed. Is it possible to list the views as well in the entities so that it will be easier for discoverability and handle permissions at a more granular level?

I have tried my best in checking the documentation and playing around in the tool but could not display the BQ views as entities.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the search and under search, navigate to Data types. here you could select data set you want and view you want to see?

[image: see image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, as you said, I am able to see the BQ views listed in the Search window. 

But I need to add these BQ views as entities in the Dataplex Asset so that there are visible when I filter for that particular zone or lake. For me, Dataplex Asset only discovers tables in the dataset at the moment.